# Equations for a simplified transistor circuit

Tags: circuit-design, resistance, ohms-law

In the following circuit:

[image]

I would like to greatly, greatly simplify how the components work just to be able to make a dumbed-down version of the equations. Let's assume the forward-voltage of the LED is 2V (and it doesn't have any other properties), and the forward voltage of the NPN transistor to be 0.7V (and simplify it so it acts like an on/off switch).

What would be the system of equations to solve for the current/voltage through the components when:

1. The switch is turned on?
2. The switch is turned off?

Comment: I've added an 'm' suffix before the .png to resize the image to 'medium' to avoid the "schematics for the deaf" appearance. The numbered list markup is `1. ` (with following space), etc..

Comment: @Transistor -- thank you.

Comment: How about transistor beta; infinity or 100 or maybe something else?

Comment: Haven't you learnt Thevenin equiv. theorem yet?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 nope -- just ohm's + kirchoff's laws so far.

Comment: Tangential: Q1 - Where did you get the circuit from? Q2 - What are you trying to do? | While the circuit's operation is understandable this is a very strange arrangement which you would perhaps never see in practice. Q3 - Is the aim to tun an LED on/off or dim  bright or ...?

Comment: I have told David numerous times ,dont design without  specs and that cct. is not how you do it. unless you specify something different as Russ hinted at.

Comment: @David542 You can learn about Thevenin equivalent for a resistor divider [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/478065/38098). I spent some effort in helping make it easier to follow. If you can read what I wrote there and understand it, then you can apply that idea to your circuit in order to simplify it, somewhat.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon this is from the book [Make Electronics](http://www.n5dux.com/ham/files/pdf/Make%20-%20Electronics.pdf), page 129. I'm just trying to understand it, really. Various current/voltage at different points in it. I believe the demonstration is to show how an alarm might work.

Comment: @jonk -- thanks, I favorited that post and I'll try and study it a bit over the next few days.

Comment: @David542 OK - the context in the (probably illegal copy of) the book makes sense. They are demonstrating how a circuit can be turned on by opening a contact. The transistor base voltage is usually held low by the 1k/10k divider - to about 12/11th V ~= 1.1 V. Ve is about 1.1-0.6 = 0.5V. This is low enough to not illumiate any "normal" LEDs. When SW1 is open the base is driven much higher by R1 and the LED lights. | It is still an unusual cct but that does not matter too much here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqYnPA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. CircuitLab version allows simulation.*

This is just a rough estimate approach.

**SW1 open**

- With R1 = 10k we'll get 0.1 mA per volt difference between V1 and Q1's base. If the LED turns on it will clamp Q1's emitter at around 2 V. That means that Q1's base will be in the region of 2.5 V. *I<sub>R1</sub>* will be about 0.95 mA. Let's say 1 mA.
- If Q1 has a gain of 100 it should be able to pass a 100 mA collector current.
- It can't. R3 is 680 Ω so the current will be limited to \$ \frac {12 - V_{LED}}{680}= 15 \ \text {mA} \$. This is a safe value for an indicator LED.

**SW1 closed**

- With SW1 closed R1 and R2 form a potential divider of 11:1. The maximum voltage that will appear on the base is \$ \frac {12}{11} = 1.1 \ \text {V} \$.
- The emitter will be one diode drop lower so about 0.4 V.
- This isn't enough to light the LED. It will be off.

You can set this up in CircuitLab, click on Simuulate | DC solver | probe the top of the LED which will add a voltage and current measure to the measurement list | Run DC Solver. The results agree pretty well with our very rough calculations.

---

> (and simplify it so it acts like an on/off switch).

This part of your question is vague.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ2atu.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. (a) The gross simplification. (b) A modest simplification.*

Figure 2b might be useful to control the LED via a really sensitive switch that couldn't handle the 15 mA LED current.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNoo3t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\tag1$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta\$:
  $$\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{C}}{\text{I}_\text{B}}\tag2$$

Using KCL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_\text{T}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_\text{D}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{D}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_\text{T}\\
\\
\beta=\frac{\text{I}_1}{\text{I}_\text{T}}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{V}_\text{BE}=\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2\\
\\
\text{V}_2=\text{V}_\text{D}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

I used Mathematica to solve this problem, using the following code:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ix == I1 + I2, I2 == I3 + IT, Ix == I3 + ID, 
   ID == I1 + IT, β == I1/IT, I1 == (Vx - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (Vx - V3)/R2, I3 == V3/R3, VBE == V3 - V2}, {ID, IT, Ix, I1, 
   I2, I3, V1, V3}]]
```

And it gives:

```
{{ID -> -((((R2 + R3) (V2 + VBE) - R3 Vx) (1 + β))/(R2 R3)), 
  IT -> (-(R2 + R3) (V2 + VBE) + R3 Vx)/(R2 R3), 
  Ix -> -(((V2 + VBE) β)/R3) - ((V2 + VBE - Vx) (1 + β))/
    R2, I1 -> (-(R2 + R3) (V2 + VBE) β + R3 Vx β)/(R2 R3),
   I2 -> -((V2 + VBE - Vx)/R2), I3 -> (V2 + VBE)/R3, 
  V1 -> Vx + R1 ((V2 + VBE)/R3 + (V2 + VBE - Vx)/R2) β, 
  V3 -> V2 + VBE}}
```

---

In your circuit we have two cases:

When (case 1) \$\text{R}_3=1000\space\Omega\$ and when (case 2) \$\text{R}_3\to\infty\$. The first case gives:

```
{{ID -> -((177 (1 + β))/100000), IT -> -(177/100000), 
  Ix -> -((3 (-31 + 59 β))/100000), 
  I1 -> -((177 β)/100000), I2 -> 93/100000, I3 -> 27/10000, 
  V1 -> 12 + (3009 β)/2500, V3 -> 27/10}}
```

And the second case:

```
{{ID -> (93 (1 + β))/100000, IT -> 93/100000, 
  Ix -> (93 (1 + β))/100000, I1 -> (93 β)/100000, 
  I2 -> 93/100000, I3 -> 0, V1 -> 12 - (1581 β)/2500, 
  V3 -> 27/10}}
```

Now, for example, assume \$\beta=250\$. We get for the first case:

```
{{ID -> -(44427/100000), IT -> -(177/100000), Ix -> -(44157/100000), 
  I1 -> -(177/400), I2 -> 93/100000, I3 -> 27/10000, V1 -> 3129/10, 
  V3 -> 27/10}}

{{ID -> -0.44427, IT -> -0.00177, Ix -> -0.44157, I1 -> -0.4425, 
  I2 -> 0.00093, I3 -> 0.0027, V1 -> 312.9, V3 -> 2.7}}
```

And for the second case:

```
{{ID -> 23343/100000, IT -> 93/100000, Ix -> 23343/100000, 
  I1 -> 93/400, I2 -> 93/100000, I3 -> 0, V1 -> -(1461/10), 
  V3 -> 27/10}}

{{ID -> 0.23343, IT -> 0.00093, Ix -> 0.23343, I1 -> 0.2325, 
  I2 -> 0.00093, I3 -> 0., V1 -> -146.1, V3 -> 2.7}}
```

Comment: I see you have posted several of these answers based on the use of MMA. Personally I have zero issues with that, but may I suggest (without any pretense) a more conventional choice of names? For example R1 and R2 for the divider, Rc for the collector resistance and Ic, Ib and Ie instead of branch numbering? It will make it easier to read the results. If you are accustomed to branch numbering, a replacement rule can fix it in a one-liner. Just my two cents.

Comment: Also, the value you computed do not seem to make sense... Id= - 0.444???

Comment: @SredniVashtar that is true, the LED is off when the switch is closed

Comment: Yep. but even in the first case: V1 = 312 V?

Comment: But in this particular circuit the BJT is in the saturation region (when SW1 is open) this is why his calculations are WRONG. And in the second case (SW1 closed) the BJT is cut-off.

Comment: @G36 yeah, he should probably scorporate the device equations from KCL and KVL equations, and provide three different set of equations for the BJT (Sat, Lin, Off), solve for the three and feed the solution to a piece of code that check for consistency and rejects the wrong solutions. (if using the highly simplified models for the transistor is what he wants - it can be didactically useful).