# Equivalent circuit of a circuit with diode and voltage sources

Tags: circuit-analysis

The goal is to find the Q point of the circuit but the author simplifies the circuit first by finding its equivalent. I need help in understanding how the author went from the original to the equivalent circuit.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyz9U.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jA6q.jpg

I can see R3 and R4 being in parallel with equivalent resistance  = 1.33 kilo ohms.  If D1 is forward biased, then R1 and R2 share the same node on one side, but they are not in parallel because of voltage sources on the other side. So how did the author combine these two? Is he using superposition to short out the voltage sources? But then where does 1.33V and 2.66V come from?

Comment: what book is this from?

Comment: Assuming that the hand-written 4 isn't -4 (which it really looks like, to me), then it's just basic Thevenin resistor divider equivalent stuff on both ends of the diode. I went through a little bit of effort to show how this Thevenin equivalence thing works with resistor dividers recently [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/478065/38098).